# Declare local table <column_definition> from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create Dynamic columns for local table. This is my example code

```
Declare @ColumnsTable AS varchar(max) =  '"column_a" varchar(100),"column_b" varchar(100), "column_c" varchar(100)'

Declare @Table AS Table (@ColumnsTable)

Select * from @Table
```

I can't use `EXEC`

Comment: `i can't use with EXEC` use sp_executesql :)

Comment: Is "I can't use `EXEC`" that you've tried it and realised because of its nested scope, the variable isn't in your outer scope, or a more fundamental limitation (i.e. you're trying to write this inside a function)?

Comment: `sp_executesql` still needs `EXEC`, @StanislavKundii. **`EXEC`** `sp_executesql @SQL;`. You can't execute dynamic SQL without using `EXEC` in some way.

Comment: GO 
sp_executesql   N'SELECT 1'

Comment: But that isn't Dynamic SQL @StanislavKundii. As soon as you add a variable or a derived literal string you get an error. Try: `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT 1;'; sp_executesql @SQL;` or `sp_executesql N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(varchar(1),1) + N';';`. Both error with different messages. You might as well replace `GO sp_executesql N'SELECT 1'` with `GO SELECT 1;`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's sarcasm or not @StanislavKundii; but actually you *do* need to create your Dynamic SQL by some kind of string concatenation; which is normally done by using the `+` operator yes. So, regardless of if your comment is sarcastic it not, it show that `GO sp_executesql N'SELECT 1'` isn't a viable option.

Comment: @StanislavKundii - you can only invoke a stored procedure without using `exec` when it appears directly as the first (executable) part of a batch. As such, *technically* you can call it without `exec` but not in any meaningful way if it's meant to be part of a batch/module/etc

Comment: Well, the only way to do such a thing is using dynamic sql, and this means the entire script that's using the table variable needs to be a part of the dynamic sql, which is going to be a nightmare to maintain. If you can use a temporary table instead of a table variable, that would make your life a little easier but you would still need some dynamic sql to create the table.